# bootstrap multiselect drop down is not dropping down

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, html-select, bootstrap-multiselect

I'm using the [bootstrap multiselect](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/) plugin and binding the data to it with knockout js. It is in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bkzb272j/213/). The options actually do get data-bound to the multiselect - You can confirm this by right clicking the multiselect element in the jsfiddle output window and inspecting it, and the `<option>`'s are indeed there. However, clicking the multiselect element does not cause the dropdown to drop down.

The [bootstrap multiselect](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/) does not seem to know that it has `<option>`'s in the `<select>`, this is proven when I use the [disableIfEmpty](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/#configuration-options-disableIfEmpty) configuration option, it disables the multiselect permanently. Why does the bootstrap multiselect not know that it has options, thus causing it to not open the drop down?

[jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bkzb272j/213/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only instantiate your multiselect widgets *after* knockout has done its rendering, which is basically *after* your apply bindings.

To get the idea, check out this forked fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/r0kbch7u/

I've basically moved the `$("#category-select").multiselect()` code from your `CategorySelect` constructor to your document loaded event listener.

Comment: Thanks. I like the dataFor way of configuring the multiselect. Any idea why the buttonWidth is not 100%? I wonder if the dataFor is not working for some reason.

Comment: I might've made an error getting the configuration file.. I'll have a look. More importantly however: I mainly wanted to show the importance of the order of `applyBindings` and `.multiselect`. The way I've implemented it in the example isn't the best way. It'd be better if you make a custom knockout component that uses its `init` method to initialize the multiselect.

Comment: Updated example: http://jsfiddle.net/r0kbch7u/1/

There seems to be something wrong with your button container as well. I've added `position: relative` because the dropdown would render outside of your view.

Comment: Perfect. The updated example works great in my website. Custom knockout components look powerful. I will use them in the future. Thanks.